# .NET Web API Stripping Slashes from Controller Name - How to disable that behavior?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm  developing a .NET Core Web API and I need to integrate against a third party that sends post requests with two trailing `/` characters before the controller name.

Example: `http://myapi//mycontroller/routename`

I can't change the third party implementation, so I have to make this work.

I tried simply adding the extra slash to the controller name, and that didn't work.
In the code example below, you can see that any arbitrary number of slashes are stripped out by .NET.

If I called the below route in Postman with all the slashes, I'd get a 404. If I use just a single slash, it hits the controller/route regardless of how many slashes are in the controller name in the code.

My controller looks like this:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("////////////controllername")]
    public class MyContorller : ControllerBase
    {
        public MyController() {}

        [Route("//////myroute")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post()
        {
            // TODO do stuff
        }
    }
```

As I said, I  can't change the third party code so I really need a way to make this work.